# NSDictionary init with object for keys

Tags: iphone, nsdictionary, ios7

```
NSLog(@"1");
NSArray *obj= [NSArray arrayWithObjects:appDel.token, nil];
NSLog(@"2");
NSArray *key= [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Token", nil];
NSLog(@"3");
NSDictionary *d= [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjects:obj forKeys:key];
NSLog(@"4");
DoSomething();
NSLog(@"5");
```

Need help with the above code. I seem to be crashing on `@"4"` (it does not print 4).

The error from Xcode:

```
'Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: ' -[NSDictionary initWithObjects:forKeys:]: count of objects (0) differs from count of keys (1)'
```

Any kind soul can point me in the right direction? It use to work till i upgraded to Xcode 5 :(

Comment: appDel.token is `nil`, I bet

Answer (score 1):

I'm most certain of the fact that `NSLog(@"%@", appDel.token);` will display `(null)`, because your token is `nil`. Verify that `appDel.token` isn't `nil`, and you won't be getting that error.
Hope this helps.

Comment: you are right, thanks i will figure out why is token null !

Thanks nemesis and borrden

Answer (score 0):

Your appDel.token is nil. Add the below reusable method in your project utility.

```
-(BOOL)isObjectEmpty:(id)object
{
    return object == nil || ([object respondsToSelector:@selector(length)] && [(NSData *)object length] == 0) || ([object respondsToSelector:@selector(count)] && [(NSArray *)object count] == 0);
}
```